# SAS - Proc Sql - Creating and merging using a new variable

Tags: sql, merge, sas

I want to create a new variable based on certain conditions in a table and merge it to another table using the newly created variable in a single data or a proc sql step.

eg)

**table 1**

---

### var new_var

### x   3x

### y   4y

### z   5z

---

**table 2**

### new_var additional_var

### 3x       a

### 3x       a

### 4y       z

and merging both the tables using the new_var in a ***single step***

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accomplish this using a join with an inline view. Inline views can save you time coding and reduce I/O operations, which is the biggest cause of slowdowns. This is particularly true on non-SSD hard drives.

```
 proc sql noprint;
      create table want as
           select var, t1.new_var, additional_var
           from table1 as t1
           LEFT JOIN
                (select new_var, 
                        CASE
                            when(<conditions>) then 'a'
                            else 'z'
                        END as additional_var
                 from table2) as t2
           ON t1.new_var = t2.new_var
 quit;
```